# PostgreSQL: SUM two values from age

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I am trying to SUM two values that are calculated using the AGE function in PostgreSQL. The AGE should be a calculated the MAX and MIN values associated with distinct (session) values from that column (Session values are distinct). The AGE function should be extracting the minutes from the (date_time) column, and then also the hours from (date_time) and multiplying that value by 60 and then summing those values together for the total number of minutes for session.

I was able to do this successfully with

```
SELECT 
session, organization, username,
((date_part('hour',age(MAX(date_time), Min(date_time)))*60) + date_part('minute',age(MAX(date_time),
Min(date_time)))) AS Duration
FROM 
analysis.user_activity
enter code here
```

However, now I am trying to be able to ORDER BY the SUM of the number that that function returns based on the SUM of the Duration by GROUP(organization), just doing ORDER BY (Duration) orders by the largest single value calculated above, not the entire aggregation by the group. This is where the problems start. First, I tried as follows:

```
SELECT
SUM(
(date_part('hour',age(MAX(date_time), Min(date_time)))*60),
date_part('minute',age(MAX(date_time), Min(date_time)))) as SumofDuration
FROM
analysis.user_activity
```

and I am getting this error: **ERROR: function sum(double precision, double precision) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 137**. I also was receiving errors about you cannot nest aggregate functions, and so I split my SELECT into multiple steps and now I have as follows.

```
SELECT
session, organization, username,
SUM((SELECT date_part('hour',age(MAX(date_time), Min(date_time)))::integer*60
FROM analysis.user_activity)
, 
(SELECT date_part('minute',age(MAX(date_time), Min(date_time)))::integer
FROM analysis.user_activity))
```

FROM
analysis.user_activity

However, this also gives me the error **ERROR: function sum(integer, integer) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 169**. I have also tried this with type *numeric*. According to the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-aggregate.html, this SHOULD be able to SUM any of the three types of data that my function produces. So what is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things. If I follow correctly, you can just do:

```
select session, organization, username,
    extract(epoch from max(date_time) - min(date_time)) / 60 duration_minutes
from analysis.user_activity
group by session, organization, username
```

Rationale: `max(date_time) - min(date_time)` gives you an interval; you can use `extract` with `epoch` to turn that to a number of seconds, then divide the result by `60` to convert that to minutes.

Note that I also fixed the aggregation query, which was missing a `group by` clause. If you want to sum the duration of all sessions, then add another level of aggregation:

```
select sum(duration_seconds) / 60 total_duration_minutes
from (
    select extract(epoch from max(date_time) - min(date_time)) duration_seconds
    from analysis.user_activity
    group by session, organization, username
) t
```

Comment: thank you very much for the quick reply. Im new to PostgreSQL and its unusual operation involving Time and Date has has me spinning my wheels. Your solution worked great, thank you again.